# How to chose some options based on their values in this multiple select drop down menu?

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu, each, multi-select

**dips** is a multiple select drop down menu and **dips_list** is an array containing some of the drop down menu values I want selected using the code below:

```
jQuery.each(dips_list, function(index,value){
     jQuery("#dips option[value='" + value + "']").attr("selected", 1);
     jQuery("#dips").multiselect("refresh");
});
```

Here's how the drop menu looks like:

```
<select id="dips" name="dips" multiple="multiple" size="10">
<option value="">Choose IP Address</option>
<option value="127.0.0.1">127.0.0.1</option>
<option value="127.0.0.2">127.0.0.2</option>
<option value="127.0.0.3">127.0.0.3</option>
<option value="127.0.0.4">127.0.0.4</option>
</select>
```

But, it does not work. Any idea why?

Comment: Add you HTML ... what does "it does not work" mean ? what are you expecting to happen ? and where is the `multiselect` method coming from ?

Comment: Do you really have a tag named dips? Or did you mean #dips? in the second line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace

```
.attr("selected", 1);
```

with

```
.attr("selected", "selected");
```

or if your using jQuery 1.6 =>

```
.prop("selected", "selected");
```

[Docs for .prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `jQuery("#dips")` instead of `jQuery("dips")` and do

```
 .find(":checkbox[value='"+value+"']").click();
```

taken from multiselect [manual](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/)

> Manually check or uncheck a checkbox?
>
> The checkboxes can be accessed after calling the "widget" method.
>   Simply manually trigger the NATIVE click event on them: